# Hiding sibling element when clicking element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

While in an `ng-repeat`, I'm trying to hide a sibling element when I click an element. Inside my `controllerClickMethod` I check to see if `item.attribute` equals the attribute value in `data-group`. How would I be able to accomplish this?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemArray">
    <div ng-click="controllerClickMethod(item)">
        <h4>
            Label
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div data-group="{item.attribute}"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This sounds like a very jQuery-esque approach.  The angular way would be to use a variable in your controller (or in a directive) along with `ng-hide` placed on the element you want to hide.

Comment: Some HTML would be beneficial to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work. Add `ng-click` and `ng-hide` directives to your elements. In your `ng-click`, throw in a function that will add `hide` property to the next sibling.

```js
angular.module('HidingPeeps', [])
.controller('Peeps', function() {
  this.peeps = [
    {name: 'Joe'},
    {name: 'Bob'},
    {name: 'Sarrah'},
    {name: 'Tom'},
    {name: 'You'}
  ];
  this.hide = function ($index) {
    if(!this.peeps[$index]) {
      $index = 0;
    }
    this.peeps[$index].hide = true;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="HidingPeeps">
     <div ng-controller="Peeps as C">
       <div ng-repeat="peep in C.peeps" ng-click="C.hide($index+1)" ng-hide="peep.hide">
         {{peep.name}}
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```